# How to allocate aligned memory from an api that has a lower alignment guarantee?

Tags: c++, alignment

if I have an API to allocate memory which guarantees that the returned pointer is aligned to n bytes, how can I allocate memory allocated to m>n bytes (only considering non-negative integral powers of two for alignment)?

my attempt would be:

```
void* alloc(size_t bytes, size_t alignment) {
  if(alignment > DEFAULT_GUARANTEE) {
    bytes += aligment - DEFAULT_GUARANTEE;
  }
  void* ptr = existing_alloc(bytes);
  uintptr_t remainder = ((uintptr_t)ptr) % alignment;
  if(remainder != 0) {
    ptr = (void*)(((uintptr_t)ptr) + alignment - remainder);
  }
  return ptr;
}
```

is that sound? is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Yes, this is probably the way to go. But stuffing pointers into size_t makes me uncomfortable and is probably UB. I would cast to char* and increment the pointer that way. (for the modulo the weird cast should not be a problem, you want the least significant bits anyway, you might want to mark that as reinterpret_cast?)

Comment: How are you going to deallocate this? I don't think classic `free` is ok with being pointed at an offset inside an allocated block. At least nothing in its man page suggests so.

Comment: @dratenik who said anything about freeing memory? Freeing memory is optional :) Jokes aside, you could store the offset from the original allocated location at the start of the allocated data, offset the returned pointer once again and then apply this offset before calling `free`. Pretty sure `delete[]` figures out the size of freed arrays using such "hidden" bytes as well.

Answer (score 0):

> is that sound?

Ability to free as original pointer head is lost. [@dratenik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63758772/how-to-allocate-aligned-memory-from-an-api-that-has-a-lower-alignment-guarantee/63759167#comment112747275_63758772)

> is there a better way of doing this?

Recommend since C++17,
use [`void* aligned_alloc( std::size_t alignment, std::size_t size )`](https://docs.w3cub.com/cpp/memory/c/aligned_alloc/).

Comment: well, I'm implementing a replacement for aligned new using Windows HeapAlloc (which only guarantees 8-byte alignment), so I cannot use aligned_alloc

Comment: If by 'windows' you actually mean 'MSVC' there is the _aligned_malloc function. That has been around for quite awhile now. I would prefer using that (and other implementation provided allocators) and selecting between them with preprocessor goop over a re-implementation.

Comment: @user1282931 If `HeapAlloc()` and _Windows_ are critical to the question, they should be included in that from the beginning to save us all time.  Else the question becomes a moving target.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Why? the question is very general and applies to all APIs that provide an alignment lower than the desired alignment

Comment: @user1282931 The nature of pointers and alignment is not something that one can make _portable_ in  C code.  `((uintptr_t)ptr) % alignment` assumes a certain memory model.  Instead the   functionality needs an implementation below what C can do.  To that end, as @SoronelHaetir suggest, use implementation provided allocaters when possible is the best approach.

Comment: it's something that can be implemented completely portable I'm convinced, as this is bottom line just pointer math. In my specific case, I'm not using implementation provided allocators because I'm allocating from multiple heaps, and afaik that has not been abstracted into the standard library. But the question of how to overallocate memory (from any source) and align pointers manually to certain alignment requirements is a valid question independent of that detail.

Comment: @user1282931 Converting a pointer to integer, adjusting the integer to a multiple of `alignment` and then converting back to a pointer assumes a memory model of pointer to/from integer that is not supported by the C spec.  Hence the usefulness of recent functions like `aligned_alloc()` which portable meets the needed functionality.

Comment: well I did add the c++ tag

Comment: @user1282931 Applies to C and C++

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica doesn't C++11 have uintptr_t exactly for that purpose?

Comment: @user1282931 No.  At least in C, and I suspect C++, `(u)intptr_t` is an optional type.